# A name for a well-informed person who is not believed?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for a well informed person who is not believed, or not listened to, or is even ridiculed?

I do not necessarily mean some one before their time... I am thinking in more general terms.

(I have googled this but the question is too broad and has too many keywords and if I try to narrow it down I lose the original meaning.)

Comment: They're *the voice of reason*.

Comment: Rather than existing answers that imply "prophet" to one degree or another, I would think a more suitable example would be a Galileo or such.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could try *[Cassandra](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Cassandra)*:-

> 1. Greek Mythology A daughter of Priam, the king of Troy, endowed with the gift of prophecy but fated by Apollo never to be believed.
> 2. One that utters unheeded prophecies.
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary]

This would be particularly apposite if the person was something of a pessimist.

Comment: Good suggestion. [William Connor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Connor), the journalist, took the pen-name *Cassandra*.

Answer (score 7):

They are [like] a **prophet in his own land**, which is based on a Bible quote - Mark 6:4.

> *A prophet is not without honor save in his own country*
>
> Words spoken by Jesus to the people of Nazareth, the town where he grew up. They refused to believe in his teaching because they considered him one of themselves and therefore without authority to preach to them.
>
> Note : The expression is **now used of anyone whose talents and accomplishments are highly regarded by everyone except those at home**.
> — [The American Heritage® New Dictionary of Cultural Literacy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/a-prophet-is-not-without-honor-save-in-his-own-country)

Answer (score 2):

If you take the ridicule and the lack of listening far enough, I like **suppressed** because it implies that there is something to be *feared* or avoided by the information the person is bringing forward. If one wants to suppress something, the implication is often that it's true, and one somehow fears or wants to avoid that truth. Therefore, there is both the *rejection*, *denialism* and refusal to listen, but at the same time the implication that the person is conveying *truth* or is "well informed" as you put it in OP.

> "This meddlesome man Galileo must be **suppressed**,” murmured the
>   University fathers as they left the square. “Does he think that by
>   showing us that a heavy and a light ball fall to the ground together
>   he can shake our belief in the philosophy which teaches that a ball
>   weighing one hundred pounds would fall one hundred times faster than
>   one weighing a single pound?"

[Galileo and the Leaning Tower of Pisa](http://www.upress.pitt.edu/htmlSourceFiles/pdfs/9780822944072exr.pdf) (2011) by Alberto A. Martínez.

> Dr. Stockmann attempts to expose a water pollution scandal in his home
>   town which is about to establish itself as a spa. When his brother,
>   the mayor, conspires with local politicians and the newspaper to
>   **suppress** the story, Stockmann appeals to the public meeting - only to be shouted down and reviled as 'an enemy of the people'. Ibsen's
>   explosive play reveals his distrust of politicians and the blindly
>   held prejudices of the 'solid majority'.

[Description](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/An_Enemy_of_the_People.html?id=BnD6IGoHdb8C) of An Enemy of the People (1882) by Henrik Ibsen.

**Suppressed** means:

> - Put down by authority or force: subdued.
> - Kept from public knowledge.
> - Stopped or prohibited from publication or revelation.
> - Excluded from consciousness.
> - Inhibited from growth or development.

[Merriam-Webster.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suppressed) Adapted, not verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

*low man on the totem pole*

*unsung expert*

And here are some related adjectives:

*marginalized* [Definition of *marginalize*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marginalize): "to relegate to an unimportant or powerless position within a society or group."

*peripheral*

*disregarded*